# Shortest geodesic loop on surface diffeomorphic to $\mathbb S^2$ not periodic.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I was wondering if it is possible to construct a surface with such a property. I am able to construct a surface such that the shortest geodesic loop passing through a particular point is not periodic, but there are shorter geodesic loops that exist elsewhere on the surface.

Comment: Could you clarify your definitions? To make these ideas distinct I guess by "loop" you just mean a curve $\gamma : [0,1] \to S^2$ with $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)$, while "periodic" requires smoothness at the base point, i.e. $\gamma : S^1 \to S^2$?

Comment: Yes. Periodic essentially means smooth at the basepoint, since geodesics have constant velocity and correspond to unique tangent vectors through a point, although I think of them mainly as geodesics that "repeat themselves". The definition I have is that a periodic geodesic has the property that for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$ that $\gamma(t+ck)=\gamma(t)$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: But a loop is by definition periodic, no?

Comment: @JohnMa: you can make any loop $[0,1] \to M$ periodic, but it might fail to be smooth where the endpoints join up - think about half of a figure-8. Thus if we're working strictly with smooth maps it makes sense to say this loop is not periodic, since there is no regular periodic extension with the same trace.

Comment: So is the question asking if the shortest geodesic loops in the surfaces are indeed smooth? @AnthonyCarapetis

Comment: Yeah, that's a reasonable way to phrase it.

Comment: I think this never occurs - if you have a geodesic loop which is not smooth at a certain point, then by zooming in to a normal neighbourhood centred on this point you should be able to replace a segment of the curve with a strictly shorter geodesic segment.

Comment: Yes, however the unique unit speed geodesic that corresponds to that segment may fail to be shorter than the non-smooth geodesic loop globally.

Unless I am missing something.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that a loop could be not smooth at a point, and still periodic. The figure 8 is a good example, taking one of the loops would fail to be smooth, but a geodesic which follows a strict figure 8 pattern would be periodic.

Comment: @billybob: right, it's a little more subtle than shrinking an arbitrary loop - you need to use the assumption that the original loop was the global minimizer in order to derive a contradiction. Have a look at the section "Existence of Geodesics on Compact Manifolds" in the first chapter of Jost's *Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis*, where it shown that the global minimizer of length amongst piecewise regular closed curves is always a smooth geodesic.

Comment: I cannot find it in the 4th edition of the book.

Is it present in earlier editions? Or are you perhaps thinking of a different book. The theorem I found in there is just about the minimizer of length between two points, but not for closed curves globally.

Comment: @billybob: looks like it's Theorem 1.4.6 in the 4th edition. It's stated both for fixed endpoints and for closed curves.